# How to implement history property and past it to Router... inside the index.tsx

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, push, browser-history

I need help.
How to implement history property to use it as a global prop and also in hole project(also in file with .ts extensions).

I need (history.push method) inside .ts (not functional components .tsx) file to redirect to the home page.

you can see images and the problem whit the history prop when I tried to pass inside Router.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJL60.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0s2F.png)

Comment: Can you confirm what versions of `history` and `react-router-dom` you have installed? Please run from your project directory `npm list history react-router react-router-dom` and report back.

Comment: Hi Drew, Thank you for your response. You can open the image in this link and see all versions for history, react-router... [link](https://ibb.co/0qZk11P)

Comment: Try the previous version of the `history` package. Uninstall `npm un -s history` and reinstall v4 `npm i -s history@4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You've the latest version of `history` installed but you've the previous version of `react-router-dom`. `react-router-dom@5` uses `history@4`.

1. Uninstall the current version: `npm un -s history`
2. Install the older version: `npm i -s history@4`